# An unanswered question is whether there are infinitely many primes that are 1 more than a power of 2

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Can someone check if I answered these two questions correctly:

1. An unanswered question is whether there are infinitely many primes that are $1$ more than a power of $2$, such as $5=2^2+1$. Find two more of these primes:
   $$4^2+1=17, 6^2+1=37$$
2. A more general conjecture is that there exist infinitely many primes of the form $n^2+1$. Exhibit five more primes of this type:
   $$10^2+1=101, 14^2+1=197, 20^2+1=401, 24^2+1=577, 26^2+1=677$$

Comment: $6$ is not a power of $2$.

Comment: my bad so 16^2+1=257

Comment: Yes, $16^2+1$ is good.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you have understood what the first question was asking, 
infinitely many primes of form 1 more than power of 2, i.e. $ 2^k + 1 = p$, not $ k^2 + 1$.

16 does work, but i just felt that perhaps you didn't understand what was being asked.

the 6 example would be a correct answer to the second question though. =P